# getTableCellRendererComponent Parameters: "Value" and "IsSelected" for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

I have a JComboBox in a JTable and am looking at the getTableCellRendererComponent documentation which explains the parameters.

```
table - the JTable that is asking the renderer to draw; can be null
value - the value of the cell to be rendered. It is up to the specific renderer to interpret and draw the value. For example, if value is the string "true", it could be rendered as a string or it could be rendered as a check box that is checked. null is a valid value
isSelected - true if the cell is to be rendered with the selection highlighted; otherwise false
hasFocus - if true, render cell appropriately. For example, put a special border on the cell, if the cell can be edited, render in the color used to indicate editing
row - the row index of the cell being drawn. When drawing the header, the value of row is -1
column - the column index of the cell being drawn
```

My confusion is "value" and "isSelected". If the "value" is to be rendered how could "isSelected" ever be false? If false why is "value" being rendered since it is not selected? What would be rendered? TIA.

**Update after camickr's clarification and some experimentation**

Apparently I only partially understand what is happening and it has presented me with a problem. When a JComboBox selection is made, the content of "value" is the selected item rather than the JComboBox instance. Thus I no longer have the instance of the JComboBox to render. I also do not see a method for "table" that lets me get the component in the current cell. How do I get the JComboBox instance so the box is rendered properly in that cell? As it is when a selection is made the JComboBox disappears and I get a runtime error for cases 2,5,6,7 which makes sense since value is now a string rather than a JComboBox instance. TIA.

```
public class TimelineCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table_, Object value_, boolean isSelected_, boolean hasFocus_, int row_,int column_) {

    Component field=null;
    String str="";
    if (value_!=null) {
        str=value_.toString();
    }
    switch (column_) {
        case 0:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 8:
            field=new JTextField();
            ((JTextField) field).setText(str);
            break;
        case 1:
            field=new JTextField();
            ((JTextField) field).setText(Double.toString((Double) value_));
            break;
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            field=(JComboBox<String>) value_;
            break;
        case 9:
            field=new JTextField();
            ((JTextField) field).setText("Add button");
            break;
        case 10:
            field=new JTextField();
            ((JTextField) field).setText("del button");
            break;
    }
    if (field instanceof JTextField) {
        Font f=field.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, (float) 14);
        field.setFont(f);
    }
    return(field);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you read the JTable tutorial??? You would NEVER store a JComboBox in a TableModel. The combo box is only used as an editor to edit the cell. Once the cell is edited the component used as the editor is removed from the table and the value from the editor is stored to the TableModel of the JTable. There is no need for you to access the combo box (or any other editor) after the cell has finished editing. Your attempted solution is wrong and since we don't know the requirement we can't offer any help. In any case you received an answer to your original question, why was it unaccepted???.

Comment: I have and that is the primary source of the confusion, I guess. After trying to clear up my own confusion I consulted numerous examples and it is like tiny passages all different. I used the default table model at the beginning and the JComboBoxes were not rendered. Those cells were just blanks. I finally got them to display by using the above. However, as I said when I click on the box an make a selection the box disappears because "value" is a string rather than a component.

Comment: My requirement is what I should think is routine and simple. I want to detect a selected item from the JComboBox  and knowing the row and column number, set a variable. I unaccepted the answer because I still have a problem and updated the OP. I thought if the OP was answered, no one would look at it any more.

Comment: `I finally got them to display by using the above.` - well your code is completely wrong and looks nothing like the code from the Swing tutorial. Read the JTable API and click on the "How to Use Tables" link where you will find working examples using a combo box. There is no need for a custom render or code like you posted above. `I unaccepted the answer because I still have a problem` - your original question about the "isSelected" value has been answered!!! Your current problem is completely unrelated to the original question and should not be asked in the same posting.

Comment: Read the tutorial. Download the working code. Understand how to use a combo box. If you still have problems with your "new" requirement the post a proper [mcve] in a new question. You have been asked to post a `MCVE` in previous questions. A few random lines of code is NOT an MCVE.

Comment: I have read it and I think I finally understand why I am going in circles. I went back to beginning code which I gleaned from the tutorial. My original problem was that the combo box does not show up until clicked. Instead, what is displayed is "javax.jswing.JComboBox". Solving that led me to using the renderer and it went down hill and in circles from there. There are some questions on this forum for solving this problem but that is what led me to where I am now. I need there to be a combobox displayed even when the current selection is "". Otherwise the user has no idea that cell is a box.

Comment: `My original problem was that the combo box does not show up until clicked` - correct, the editor is not displayed until the cell is in editing mode. `what is displayed is "javax.jswing.JComboBox".` - and I already told you that is completely wrong. You should NEVER store a Swing component in the TableModel. A TableModel is used to store data, not Swing components. You did NOT follow the examples from the tutorial.

Comment: The solution is to create a custom renderer for the column containing the data that is edited using a combo box. The renderer will only be used for a column with a combo box, not JTextFields. The tutorial shows how to add a renderer for a column. However, apparently you don't want an answer to that question since you haven't posted a proper question with your [mcve] showing how you attempted to implement a renderer for a combo box.. This posting already contains an answer to the original question. A posting should not contain multiple questions. Answer can only be given to a single question.

Comment: The  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is the tutorial itself. Simply include 'comboBox.addItem("");' as the first item. I cannot see anything in that tutorial that explains how to fix that problem.

Comment: I forgot to ask where you think I am adding a combobox to a table model? I added it in the renderer but I'm not even using that, as I said I went back to my original code from the tutorial.

Comment: `The Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is the tutorial itself.` - no, you question is about displaying a column with a combo box. All the other data in the other columns is irrelevant to the problem. The [mcve] should reflect this. It will be 20-20 lines of code. A few lines to create the frame. A couple to create the table. A couple to add items to the combo box. I'm not going to guess exactly what you have changed from the demo code. If you can't be bothered to post the exact code so we can see exactly what you have done then you really don't want any help.

Comment: You said: `My original problem was that the combo box does not show up until clicked. Instead, what is displayed is "javax.jswing.JComboBox". ` - well, something is wrong. You changed something in the demo code. Since you refuse to post the `MCVE`, I simply made a guess. I have no more time to waste making guesses. You have been given plenty of help and still haven't accepted the answer, so good luck getting help in the future as you obviously don't appreciate the time I have spent helping and you haven't listened to any advice given.

Comment: Welcome to my world of going in circles. As I explained, I changed back to the original code from the tutorial. Now, are you telling me when you run that exact code you are seeing a comboxbox before clicking the cell?

Comment: I have no idea what circles you are talking about. I have already told you that you need a custom renderer if you want to see a combo box before clicking on the cell. I have also told you that your current approach is completely wrong. I have told you it is simple to create the renderer but I can't answer two questions in one posting. I have also asked you to post a proper [mcve], not just copy the code from the demo, since all you care about is the column with a combo box. You are going in circles because you don't listen to suggestions.

Comment: Sorry if I seem dense but I guess we need to do a reset. Running the demo unchanged demonstrates the problem. There is nothing in the demo display that indicates the "SportColumn" is a combobox until it is clicked. That is the problem I am trying to resolve and I do use your suggestions. You complained that my renderer looked nothing like the tutorial so I used the default renderer like the tutorial. Now you say I have to go back to a custom renderer which the tutorial does not use. Circles. In any case, all I need is to get the demo to display the combox without clicking first.

Comment: Yes you need a reset. I have told you several times, `the original question about "value" and "isSelected" was answered long ago`. So this question should be "accepted". So now you have a completely new question on how to create a custom renderer to render a combo box in a cell. Again, you have been told only one question per posting. Until you accept this answer and ask a new question, with a proper [mcve], an answer will not be provided.

Comment: Yes, because you moved me away from the this attempt back to my original problem which I tried to solve heading down this wrong path. I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you click on a cell the selected row changes.

So every cell in the row needs to be rendered since the row highlighting needs to change.

Within the row, only a single cell can be selected an any one time.

Also, all the cells of the previously selected row need to be repainted without highlighting.

So the basic answer is that the method is called multiple times, once for each cell and the parameters will be different.

Comment: I think I was not clear. I am not talking about selecting a cell but rather the selection from the JComboBox in that cell. The content of "value" that I see is the selected item.

Comment: You were clear. Not sure what you don't understand about my answer. The method can be invoked for a variety of reasons, repainting an edited cell is only one of them. The method needs a general parameter signature. So the isSelected parameter value changes as required. So when you edit a cell, yes the is selected will obviously always be true, but the method can be invoked at other times, when the cell will not be selected. I gave you an simple  example of this process.

Comment: That was what I did not understand. I did not know that the renderer would be called other than when initialized or when an item was selected (clicked). Thanks.